# ruby rails how to get path to named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

How to get the path helper for a named route?

**routes.rb**

```
match 'report/monitor_id/:monitor_id/week_ending_date/:week_ending_date' => 'report#index'
```

How do I get the path helper for a named route? when I do rake routes, there's nothing in front

```
/report/monitor_id/:monitor_id/week_ending_date/:week_ending_date(.:format)        report#index
```

Is there a way to get report_monitor_id_week_ending_date_path(monitor_id, week_ending_date)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give it a name with the `:as` parameter:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

Ex:

```
match 'exit' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
```

Which should provide the helpers:

```
logout_path
logout_url
```

Not sure what you want your route to be named, but maybe something like:

```
match 'report/monitor_id/:monitor_id/week_ending_date/:week_ending_date' => 'report#index', :as => :weekly_monitor_report
```

Which I believe will give you the helpers that allow passing the parameters in the order they are specified in the route definition:

```
weekly_monitor_report_path(:monitor_id, :week_ending_date)
weekly_monitor_report_url(:monitor_id, :week_ending_date)
```

Comment: The :as will put that in the url; eg http://localhost:3000/weekly_monitor_report instead of http://localhost:3000/report/monitor_id/xxx/week_ending_date/yyy.

Looks like I can use nested resources

**route.rb**

`    resource :report do
        resources :monitor_ids do
            resources :week_ending_dates do
                resource :report
            end
        end
    end
`